# How to typeset curly brackets in equations

Tags: equations, cases

Please, how can I typeset the equation in the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You make it easier to help people if you give some code, showing your tries. In this case I'd look at the [mathtools](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) manual. Look for cases, matrices and paired delimiters.

Comment: @Tee I have given a point of departure only because I do not want to redo all the typing.

Comment: @Denis thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you load the `mathtools` package for its `dcases*` environment and `\coloneqq` macro. And, do use `bmatrix` environments for the column vectors that are encased in square brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for dcases* env. and \coloneqq macro
\begin{document}
\[
G_{\chi}(\eta) \coloneqq
\begin{dcases*}
\bigl(
  [T_{u,1}^*, T_{u,2}^*],\tau_y,0,\eta_c
\bigr)
  & if $\tau_u=0$ and $\tau_y>0$ \\[\jot]
\bigl(
  \tau_u,[T_{y,1}^*, T_{y,2}^*],0,F_c^s(\eta)
\bigr)
  & if $\tau_u>0$ and $\tau_y=0$ \\[\jot]
\left\{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    [T_{u,1}^*, T_{u,2}^*] \\ \tau_y \\ 0 \\ \eta_c
  \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \tau_u \\ [T_{y,1}^*, T_{y,2}^*] \\ 0 \\F_c^s(\eta)
  \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
  & if $\tau_u=0$ and $\tau_y=0$
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A point of departure could be

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
X = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
D & C
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
  & \text{if $x=p$}  \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Small suggestion: write `\text{if $x=p$}`, semantically `if $x=p$` is the entire comment. If writing it this way one can also avoid situations like `\text{if } x=p \text{ and } y>0` and instead write the straight forward `\text{if $x=p$ and $y>0$}`

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the suggestion. I am implementing it in my proto-answer.